# Cannot see IIS on "Add Role Services" on Server Manager, How can I install IIS?

Tags: iis, installation

I have to install IIS on a server buut I cannot install it on Server Manager, because it is not listed on "Add Role Services" on Server Manager.

How can I install IIS on the server? My server is 2008 version.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a role service. It's a role.

You will find it by going to Manage > Add Roles and Features:

[image]

[image]

Comment: my server is windows server 2008. So, I think it is called "Add Role Services", am I right?

Comment: No. The screen you are looking at it trying to add roles to an existing service (in your case, file server). IIS is a totally seperate role that you need to add.